# Youtube api to get advance statistics per video per day

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have been trying to get the video list of our youtube channel and advance statistics like avg view duration, subscribers gained, watch time, etc.
These statistics do exist in Youtube analytics Web GUI. But I could not find how I can implement that per video via API.

I have tried youtubeAnalytics.reports.query API - but unable to get the advanced statistics.

with these parameters

- ids : channel==MINE
- filter = video==
- startdate: 2019-02-15
- enddate: 2019-02-20
- metrics likes- dislikes avgviewDuration,
- dimension: day

> and other try with

- dimension day,video
  I am getting null data or query not implemented.

Comment: Is there any reason you need YouTube Data API *(which is kind of limited for specific scenarios, like this one)* instead using YouTube Analytics?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I did try that but I am getting query not supported error.
id:channel==MINE

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I did try that but I am getting query not supported error.
id: channel==MINE
filter: video==videoID
start/enddate : febuary 2019
metric: views 
dimension: gender
 
and here 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query
i am not getting any data for specific video.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what you have tried. Unfortunately, I haven't used YouTube Analytics *(yet)*, but If you include the query, the description of the error(s) you got, someone else who has more knowledges might be more helpful. Also, add your comments as part of your question instead.